# PHP Increment value by 150 if number is 1 to 2

Tags: php

I'm building a shipping website
I want to increment the value depending on the number of items.

Example
default fee is 150

```
    if numItem 1 to 2 = 150,
    if numItem 3 to 4 = 300,
    if numItem 5 to 6 = 450,
    if numItem 7 to 8 = 600,
    if numItem 9 to 10 = 750,
```

and So on every additional 2 items it adds 150 for the shipping fee

I have this PHP code but it didn't work

```
    <?php
            $fee = 150;
            for($i = 0;$i<$numOrders;$i++) {
               if($numOrders % 2 == 0) {
                   $res = $numOrders / 2;
                   $shippingFee = $fee * $res;
               }

               if($numOrders % 2 == 1) {
                    $res = $numOrders / 2;
                    $shippingFee = $res;
               }

               $shippingFee = $numOrders * $i;

            }
        ?>
```

thank you

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: If you want to mark your question as solved, then use the tick mark next to the answer that helped you the most. Writing "Solved" is not the way to do it on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just writing this code should help:
The ceil() method increases the number to be whole (ceiling).

```
$numItem = 5;    
$shippingAmount = (ceil($numItem / 2)) * 150;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ceil()` function to get a whole number after dividing by 2. Simply multiply this against 150:

```
$numItem = 7;
echo ceil($numItem / 2) * 150;
```

Comment: the value is still returning 0. Thank you

Comment: Hi is now working, I forgot to change the variable $numItem with my variable, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a int division and then multiply by 150:

```
$amount = ceil($numItem/2)*150;
```

Comment: This won't work. intval(1 / 2) = 0. 0 * 150 = 0, whereas OP wants it to be 150.

Comment: i know, i've edited the answer while you was posting the comment